# Error on Project Customization

Tags: acumatica

While I was trying to customize the project.  I got the following error. Here is the screenshot below:

[image]

When I tried to see Trace, it's empty.

The version is 6.1.

Comment: " trying to customize the project." what exactly?

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I was trying to edit the customization project.

Comment: I have seen this error before - was frustrating with no trace detail. I dont recall the fix other than we had a bad project.xml file i think. What did you recently change or trying to change? Does this show when you view the project detail page (Click on hyperlink of project name)?

Comment: Exactly. This happens to me when I try to click on the link of Customization Project name.
http://www.screencast.com/t/sT5GOazof

Comment: This is weird, but I found out that there was problem with unpublished customization projects. Then I select the projects, and did Publish. Then, clicking on project name would popup the window without any error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see what causes problems while publishing customization. I propose you to use method divide and conquer. Customization in itself is just zip file with some files inside of it. The main backbone of customization is file project.xml. Little bit more about customization structure I've described in mine blog [here](https://blog.zaletskyy.com/acumatica-customization-without-acumatica-gui) and [here](https://blog.zaletskyy.com/customization-internals-part-2). Split customization in two parts and publish half of customization. If it will be published, then problem lies in second part. If problem will persist then problem is in first part of customization. After localizing problem you can think about what to do with problematic part.

Comment: Any idea what to do if this issue persists on every screen when logging into Acumatica including the Customization screen? I tried restoring the website directory to a working snapshot's copy but it seems like the customization crashed the instance.

Comment: First idea that comes to my mind to un-publish customization. If that idea will not help then question is how that Acumatica is hosted: at your computer or at cloud of Acumatica?

Comment: Unable to Unpublish because after logging in, it gives the error shown. The instance is hosted at premise of client's.

Comment: Good. I propose to do the following in order to restore to clean condition. 1. Make back up of current database. 2. Make back up of folder in which Acumatica is installed. 3. From folder where acumatica is installed delete everything from folder CstPublished ( this is the folder were customized pages are stored ). 4. Delete from folder bin of Acumatica any files that are related to published customization

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 needed for having possibility to preserve current state of Acumatica. After steps 1 - 4 you'll still have some error messages, but hopefully Acumatica will be in more or less workable condition

Comment: Ahmed, Bikash, any news?

Comment: Sorry @YuriyZaletskyy for not updating the status. My problem had been resolved. To be honest  I can't recall exactly but your answers is logical in debugging the cause.